# Editing a single-column text file into multiple columns

Tags: linux, bash, unix, textedit

I have a large set of text files that are currently in single columns, each row representing a time-point for an `fMRI` session.

I want to now split this single column into multiple columns so that I can make a time-series of the signal.

So, for example: 
one text file has 351 rows (time-points).
My experiment consisted of 8 40-volume blocks, with an additional 31 volumes of rest period (i.e., 8*40+31=351).
Now, I want to convert this text file to be in the below format:

```
8(w)x40(h)+1x31...
```

i.e.,

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

to

```
a d
b e
c f
```

Thank you for all your help in advance!!

Comment: how should I understand your abcdef example with the rule `8(w)x40(h)+1x31...` ? what are `w` and `h`?

Comment: @Kent Wild guess at width and height.

Comment: @123 and Kent for your help! 

123, unfortunately, your suggest gives me
a b
c d
e f

whereas I require...

a d
b e
c f

any solutions??

Answer (score 0):

for your example this works:

```
split -l 3 file0 # split file into chunks of 3 lines
nl xaa > file1 # add linecount for join
nl xab > file2
join file1 file2 > pre # join based on linecount colum
sed 's/ *[0-9]*.//' pre > result # remove linecount colum
```

But the Solution proposed by 123's comment (xargs -n3 < file) is much simpler and results only in a transposed table!